# What is the simplest way to extract and write raw RGB data to a file from BitMap?

Tags: c#, image, bitmap, rgb

What is the simple and fastest way to extract raw RGB data from a BITMAP and write the raw data to a file(say .rgb)?

Comment: Are you talking about .NETs System.Drawing.Bitmap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bitmap is already 'RAW' if it is 24-bit color. In that case, simply strip the [BITMAPHEADER](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format).

Comment: Not true: Bitmap *has padding*, i.e. rows must contain a multiple of 4 _bytes_. So if you have an image width of 101 pixels, this means 303 bytes, so the next row will start at offset 304, skipping one byte.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, assuming its unpaletted 24 bit bmp, just strip the header and read the bytes in. IIRC you might also need to reverse the byte ordering too as when reading bitmaps from files byte for byte they come in as BGR.